# Building server that spawns ffmpeg instances to stream mp4 files to RTMP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp

We are building a server that streams a `mp4` file to any RTMP server (Facebook, Twitch) and we might have several streams running at the same time.

We plan to have up to 1080p 30fps videos ~ 5000 bitrate, using ffmpeg, and we have two concerns:

1. How do I recover from a packet loss or a connection drop? Since we are streaming from an `mp4` file, we don't want to start all over.
2. What are the recommended resources to have up to 100 streams going on at the same time? We sure will do some testing, but it would be nice if there's a formula to calculate that.

So we are creating a `node.js` server that reads our database to check if there are any streams that should start, and then we spawn a child process `ffmpeg` to start streaming to a given RTMP link.

Thanks.